# Typescript always throws a warning for this hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, react-tsx

I am trying to use a typescript with this hook but it can't figure out what type should I pick for the parameters ref and handler:

```
function useOnClickOutside(ref: HTMLDivElement | null, handler: Function) {
  useEffect(
    () => {
      const listener = (event) => {
        // Do nothing if clicking ref's element or descendent elements
        if (!ref.current || ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
          return;
        }
        handler(event);
      };
      document.addEventListener("mousedown", listener);
      document.addEventListener("touchstart", listener);
      return () => {
        document.removeEventListener("mousedown", listener);
        document.removeEventListener("touchstart", listener);
      };
    },
    [ref, handler]
  );
}
```

What i wrong in this line?

```
function useOnClickOutside(ref: HTMLDivElement | null, handler: Function)
```

Comment: What is the warning that you get from TS?

Comment: I think `React.MutableRefObject` can be used here. As `React.useRef` will return this type. Also `event.target` needs some typing. Please have a look at this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-fire-p66c9b?file=/src/App.tsx).

Comment: @AWolf I am using arrow function as an argument () => {setToggle(false)} and Function type is not working for that

Answer (score 1):

If typescript is setup in your IDE, you can hover your mouse over any value to get it's type.

For example, if you make a ref with `useRef` and hover over `ref`:

```
const ref = useRef<HTMLElement>()
// const ref: MutableRefObject<HTMLElement | undefined>
```

And then if you hover over `addEventListener` you'll get another type:

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", listener);
// Document.addEventListener<"mousedown">(type: "mousedown", listener: (this: Document, ev: MouseEvent) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined): void (+1 overload)

document.addEventListener("touchstart", listener);
// Document.addEventListener<"touchstart">(type: "touchstart", listener: (this: Document, ev: TouchEvent) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined): void (+1 overload)
```

In that type you'll see the `listener` argument typed as:

```
(this: Document, ev: MouseEvent) => any
// or
(this: Document, ev: Touchevent) => any
```

1. You can disregard the `this` type as long your function doesn't reference `this`.
2. If you don't use the return value from the function, then you should change the return type to `void`.
3. Since this needs to work for both mouse and touch events, you can use a union of both.

Then your `handler` type becomes:

```
(ev: MouseEvent | Touchevent) => void
```

So your custom hook can be declared as:

```
function useOnClickOutside(
  ref: MutableRefObject<HTMLElement | undefined>,
  handler: (ev: MouseEvent | TouchEvent) => void
) {
  //...
}
```

---

Lastly, the `listener` function you declare needs its argument typed. That listener needs to accept the same eventThis is simply:

```
const listener = (event: MouseEvent | TouchEvent) => {
  //...
}
```

[Working example with no type errors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMCiAzb6DGMANChgErrYkCyyMAhgEYA26F2A8owFYHwC+cbFAgg4Acijp6hcQCg52ZADtCwCMtLoOygMLNg+ANYc6qYABN0ACinYAXHFoMWbSl16EAPAAkAKtQAMpisIOjK8AA+KMpW2MDK6BYAfCQAFvSxrFCO1ugAbo7UEGhY+eFRcH4l+GmY5REAlHAAvMlw+RCWzQhycFo4eITWff1w1s1tiKNjcPgaqPAGi+HoUK3jBRVFJRj1FXDR1ci1+02t7b2zswD0N3AAIhBwyhAwaQkA5nDA2HMGxi+cDs4lQcHQoQO0DgVlQ+HCVgi4MhEVQM2uv3GAEI7AA6fDIKBSJGRaJ5BowXEMKCfdDwBKLTLwiB-fxBELoMJIgBk3OBlHxhOJlPmEXoDPJFSp9BpdMa8um12uUhghOUAG50bN+FqxhksmtJU1NUr+CbrhYIASuZT6BYLGcYIFgCtElBrAAiEC7JIQADuyg9JGWMFWUEa5tmlutUrtDopztdho9MBqaUZsCDcBDYYjupVavGk0uuv60eQNtxUm95UdidDbs93tKloDWZzbrzSrLVorUurEFrCZdDeTqZO6epMHbI9zkbGZvR-CI6IA2nZ0pkLNkALqjPP8IA)